# Listar para frontend valores de várias tabelas

Tags: javascript, node.js, react

Boa tarde,
Sou iniciante em react e node.js e estou com um problema.

Tenho uma tabela numa página web em que vai receber os dados de uma viagem. As colunas (Id localidades, nome, data,hora) estão presentes no model pedidos_viagem, mas a coluna "nome localidades" pretendia listar o nome das localidades através do id. Os ids desta localidade constam na coluna "Id localidades", contudo ao listar dá me o erro: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'designacao' of undefined".

Para melhor compreensão da tabela, na primeira linha de dados, o 1 é o id da partida e o 124 é id da chegada.
Junto envio foto da tabela bem como do controller e dos models.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a inserção dos dados na tabela é feita na função `loadFillData()` presente neste código:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../../assets/css/Pagamentos.css'
import 'js-datepicker/dist/datepicker.min.css';
import '../../../assets/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { data } from 'jquery';
const datepicker = require('js-datepicker');

class Pagina extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pag_pendentes: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const picker = datepicker('#calendario', {
            formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
                input.value = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date)
            }
        });

        const url = "http://localhost:3001/operadora/pendente";
        axios.get(url)
        .then(res=>{
            if(res.data.success){
                const data = res.data.data;
                this.setState({pag_pendentes:data});
            }else{
                alert("Erro");
            }
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            alert(error)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="div-filtragem">
                    <label className="Label_DatePicker">Data inicio:</label>
                    <input placeholder="Selecione uma data" type="text" id="calendario" className="form-control DatePicker datepicker" style={{ width: "auto" }} />
                    <label className="Label_DatePicker">Data fim:</label>
                    <input placeholder="Selecione uma data" type="text" id="calendario" className="form-control DatePicker datepicker" style={{ width: "auto" }} />
                    <button type="button" className="ButtonFilter ">Filtrar</button>
                </div>
                <div className="div_tabela">

                    <table className="table tabela" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">IDs localidades</th>
                                <th scope ="col">nome localidades</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                                <th scope="col">Data</th>
                                <th scope="col">Hora</th>
                                <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            
                            {this.loadFillData()}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    loadFillData(){
        console.log(this.state.pag_pendentes);
        return this.state.pag_pendentes.map((data, index) => {
            
            return (
                <tr key ={index}>
                    <td className="td_viagem">{data.partida + "-"+data.chegada}</td>
                    <td>{data.pp.designacao + "-"+data.pc.designacao}</td>
                    <td>{data.pessoa.p_nome + " " +data.pessoa.u_nome}</td>
                    <td>{data.data_viagem}</td>
                    <td>{data.hora_viagem}</td>
                    <td>10€</td>
                </tr>

            )
        });
    }
}

export default Pagina;
```

O controller desta página é este:

```
var Viagem = require('../../model/viagem');
var Pedido_viagem = require('../../model/pedido_viagem');
var Estado = require('../../model/estado');
var Pessoa = require('../../model/pessoa');
var Partida = require('../../model/freguesias');
var Chegada = require('../../model/freguesias');
const sequelize = require('../../model/database');

const op_pagamentos = {}
sequelize.sync()
op_pagamentos.pendentes = async(req,res) => {
    const data = await Pedido_viagem.findAll({
        include: [Viagem],
        include: [Estado], 
        include:[{
                model: Partida,
                as:'pp',
                attributes:['designacao']
            },
            {model: Chegada, 
                as:'pc',
                attributes:['designacao']}],
        include: [{
            model: Pessoa,
            attributes:['p_nome', 'u_nome']}],
        where:{ 
            estado : "3",
        },
            order :[[ 'id', 'asc' ]],

    })
    .then(function (data) {
        return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Erro: ' + error);
        return error;
    });
    res.json({success: true, data: data});

}

module.exports = op_pagamentos;
```

model pedido_viagem:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = require('./database');
var Municipe = require('./pessoa');
var Estado  = require('./estado_pedido');
var Partida  = require('./freguesias');
var Chegada  = require('./freguesias');


var pedido_viagem = sequelize.define('pedido_viagem',{
    id:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    municipe:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references:{
            model:Municipe,
            key:'id'
        },
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },

    partida:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references:{
            model:Partida,
            key:'id'
        },
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    chegada:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references:{
            model:Chegada,
            key:'id'
        },
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    data_viagem: {
        type:Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    hora_viagem:{
        type:Sequelize.TIME,
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    aceita_partilha:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    necessidades_especiais: {
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    bagagem: {
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    estado:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references:{
            model: Estado,
            key:'id'
        }
    }
},
{
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true
});

pedido_viagem.belongsTo(Municipe,{foreignKey:'municipe'});
pedido_viagem.belongsTo(Partida,{as:'pp',foreignKey:'partida'});
pedido_viagem.belongsTo(Chegada,{as:'pc',foreignKey:'chegada'});

module.exports= pedido_viagem;
```

model freguesias:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = require('./database');
var tipo_freguesia = require('./tipo_frequesia');;

var freguesia = sequelize.define('freguesias',{
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    designacao: {
         type:Sequelize.CHAR(50),
         allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },   
    localizacao: {
        type: Sequelize.CHAR(100),
        allowNull:false // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    zona: {
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    },
    tipo_freguesia:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        regerences:{
            model:tipo_freguesia,
            key:'id'
        },
        allowNull:false  // coloca variável NOT NULL
    }
},
{
 timestamps: false,
 freezeTableName: true,
});

module.exports = freguesia;
```

Por favor, agradeço imenso se alguém me conseguir ajudar. Sou iniciante e não estou a entender o porquê de me estar a dar este erro.

Cumprimentos a todos

Answer (score 0):

Ele basicamente está dizendo que não existe o data.pc, a melhor maneira para verificar isso é dar um console.log nesse data para ver o que está retornando.

Comment: O console.log, mostra todos os valores presentes no model pedido_viagem e mostra o nome da pessoa, mas não mostra nada do model freguesias. Ou seja, não mostra nem a partida nem a chegada, que era o que eu pretendia

Answer (score 0):

Pq voce não tira o as: "pp" e as: "pc" e chama diretamente data.Partida.designacao e data.Chegada.designacao

Comment: Penso que seria a mesma coisa que fazer com o as:"pp" e as:"pc". Além disso, dá erro na mesma

Comment: Acho que seria interessante colocar o código do model também

Comment: Já editei e coloquei. Antes de mais, obrigado por me estar a ajudar

Comment: Esses imports estão no plural:

var Partida = require('../../model/freguesias');
var Chegada = require('../../model/freguesias');

E o exports está no singular:

module.exports = freguesia;

Comment: não é disso. o model é "freguesias.js". No controller, ao colocar o `include : [ model: partida]` e o de chegada em cima do `include: [model: Pessoa]`, mostra as partidas e chegadas mas deixa de mostrar o nome da pessoa... dá o mesmo erro mas neste caso para p_nome

Comment: Também não é disso. mesmo com esse require dá erro.

Comment: Já tentou colocar um include separado para Partida e Chegada

Comment: Também não é isso. Penso que não tem nada a ver com o código do include. Ao inverter a ordem dos includes pessoa e partida, consigo mostrar a partida e chegada mas já não mostra o nome da pessoa